# javascript getHours() is not a function

Tags: javascript

I want to add a minute offset to the current time and display it in 12 hour format

```js
var now = new Date();
var offset = 1000;
var timeOffset = now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + offset);
var hours = timeOffset.getHours();
var minutes = timeOffset.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
var newTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
console.log(newTime)
```

why is this throwing `TypeError: dateTime.getHours is not a function`?

Comment: `.setMinutes()` does not return a Date instance.

Comment: @Pointy is correct, it returns "The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes

Answer (score 1):

`setMinutes` set the minutes on the current date-object so take `now` for further calculations.

```js
var now = new Date();
var offset = 1000;
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + offset);
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
var newTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
console.log(newTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line does not work as you intened;

```
var timeOffset = now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + offset);
```

`timeOffset` will be an integer with a number of miliseconds. Instead off defining a second var, you can alter the `now` variable like so;

```js
var now = new Date();
var offset = 1000;

now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + offset);

var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
var newTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
console.log(newTime)
```